# PHP Put more than one object into json file

Tags: php, json

So I've been working on this PHP API thing for a while, and it would save JSON to a PHP file. The code works, but only allows 1 object. How do I add another object without removing the old JSON (Appending JSON)

```
<?php
//-- Parameters --\\
$id = $_GET['id'];
$language = $_GET['language'];
$filter = $_GET['filter'];
$commands = $_GET['commands'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
$members = $_GET['members'];

//-- Read and Parse JSON --\\
$string = file_get_contents("./Data/Guilds.json");
$json_a = json_decode($string, true);

if(isset($json_a[$id])) {

}
else {
    //-- Initialize Array --\\

    $obj[$id] = Array();

    //-- Set Array Objects --\\

    $obj[$id]["language"] = $language;
    $obj[$id]["filter"] = $filter;
    $obj[$id]["commands"] = $commands;

    $obj[$id]["information"]["name"] = $name;
    $obj[$id]["information"]["members"] = $members;

    //-- Encode and Write --\\

    $fp = fopen('./Data/Guilds.json', 'w+');
    fwrite($fp, $json);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: You create `$json_a`, but never use it other than checking for an existing key. You create a new `$obj` instead of appending to `$json_a`.. and the write `$json`, which you don't show the creation of here.

Comment: ^ This is the answer lmao